# Is it possible to block external requests to an API?

Tags: nginx

I have nginx serving a python REST API at api.example.com. When a user enters example.com, a couple of AJAX requests are fired from the user to api.example.com. Is it possible to block requests to the API if the user is not on example.com? Would CORS help me here? Thanks in advance!

The objective here is to make the API only accessible from the main website and blocked to the external websites.

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX requests will have a referrer header, which will be set to the page that the request are coming from. You can see this with FireBug on this question:

[image]

You can filter server-side on this. However it is trivial to fake if the user is determined enough.

Another option is to keep an instant log of the requests to your site in the last x minutes, cross-reference the list of known IP addresses against each API request - but this is also trivial to fake, as they can just poll your site every few minutes to keep an active record in your table.

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you trying to solve?  What kind of requests are you looking to block?

Generally, you'd want to check the `Referer` header, to determine where the resource was linked from.  But, that's easily fabricated by someone generating requests to your API (if that's actually the problem you're having).

Verifying that someone's a human before they're allowed to make an API call is where you'd need a CAPTCHA.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit. The objective here is to make the API only accessible from the main website and blocked from external websites. I don't want website abc.com or any other user that is not an browser at example.com to be able to query the API. Is this possible?

Comment: @Clash Sure, just check the `Referer` header - but again, that's client generated, so a crafted request could circumvent this.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this that can not be circumvented?

Comment: @Clash Sure, but that assurance carries a very steep cost in complexity.  As a good example, take a look at the security structures that Twitter has put around their APIs.  You need to decide what level of security assurance versus complexity that you'd like to have for your application, but there is no solution that's both bulletproof and simple.

Comment: Does the site have authentication? If it does, then your usual session based authentication might be sufficient. Otherwise you can try something like a form key http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys/